# pypm install (package) gives warning: no such package found for requirement

Tags: python, twisted, orbited, pypm

When I try `pypm install twisted` `pypm install morbid` `pypm install orbited` I get

```
warning: no such package found for requirement "twisted"; try PyPM Index:
http://code.activestate.com/pypm/search:twisted/

warning: no such package found for requirement "morbid"; try PyPM Index:
http://code.activestate.com/pypm/search:morbid/

warning: no such package found for requirement "orbited"; try PyPM Index:
http://code.activestate.com/pypm/search:orbited/
```

Does anyone know why none of these packages are recognised? Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Comment: Here they say that command should be right.. http://code.activestate.com/pypm/twisted/

Comment: Yes, but pypm install (anything) doesnt work, even though I have pypm installed

Comment: Please indicate which version of ActivePython you are using. What is the output of `pypm info`? I bet you are using either 3.1 or 3.2, as none of these packages are available for Python 3 yet.